# Share build number between VSTS builds

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have multiple builds in VSTS and I want to share the build number from 1 build with a subsequent one.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give some more details about why you need to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the previous build number in the current build?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible for now.

The build number format only can be used for a certain build.

But [variable groups](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/variable-groups) (only can be used for release recently) may help across builds in future.